# MySQL merge data into one column

Tags: mysql

I have this query result:

```
|  Activity    |  Player   |
| -----------  | --------- |
| Play Tennis  | John Doe  |
| Play Tennis  | Jane Doe  |
| Play Bowling | Jonah Doe |
```

But the goal is supposed to be like this:

```
| Activity     | Player              |
| -----------  | ------------------- |
| Play Tennis  | John Doe            |
|              | Jane Doe            |
| Play Bowling | Jonah Doe           |
```

or like this:

```
| Activity     | Player              |
| -----------  | ------------------- |
| Play Tennis  | John Doe, Jane Doe  |
| Play Bowling | Jonah Doe           |
```

How do I achieve that query?
I would like to share my current query and the full columns here but I couldn't due to a strict rules on my workplace (I hope everyone could understand it)
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second format you could use `GROUP_COUNCAT()`:

```
SELECT Activity, GROUP_CONCAT(Player) AS Player
FROM table_name
GROUP BY Activity
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fe2ede07dd4d0cde3b199a48219c1f0f)